# How can I add a title to an iOS push notification?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I send push notifications to my client application with a cloud script and on Android the notification looks like this:

> Welcome message
>
> Hello

I want to show the notification identically on iOS, but on my iOS device it looks like this:

> Hello
>
> Hello

How can I show the correct title("Welcome message") in my push notification on iOS?

**UPDATE:** I found out that my message title("Welcome message") is not in `userInfo`, just the message body("Hello"). Why is the message title("Welcome message")not included in `userInfo`?

[image]

```
public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo) {
    ProcessNotification(userInfo, false);
}
void ProcessNotification(NSDictionary options, bool fromFinishedLaunching) {
    // Check to see if the dictionary has the aps key.  This is the notification payload you would have sent
    if (null != options && options.ContainsKey(new NSString("aps"))) {
        //Get the aps dictionary
        NSDictionary aps = options.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;

        string alert = string.Empty;

        if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("alert"))) alert = (aps[new NSString("alert")] as NSString).ToString();

        if (!fromFinishedLaunching) {
            //Manually show an alert
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(alert)) {
                NSString alertKey = new NSString("alert");
                UILocalNotification notification = new UILocalNotification();
                notification.FireDate = NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceNow(10);
                notification.AlertTitle = aps.ObjectForKey(alertKey) as NSString;
                notification.AlertBody = aps.ObjectForKey(alertKey) as NSString;
                notification.TimeZone = NSTimeZone.DefaultTimeZone;
                notification.SoundName = UILocalNotification.DefaultSoundName;
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduleLocalNotification(notification);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/rich-notifications-ios-10/ .You can convert it to c#.

Comment: I don't know how to convert that to c#. I know that this line is wrong: notification.AlertTitle = aps.ObjectForKey(alertKey) as NSString; But I don't know how to change the code so that I can get the correct title("Welcome message") in the notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key "alert" in your push payload is read by the OS as the title of the notification.
If you want to show any custom title to your notification there are a few possible ways

**Easy Way**

Change the value of payload key "alert" to the your custom message.

**Hard Way**

Create Notification service extension.

It’s a small chunk of code that is run just before the phone shows a notification you’ve sent, and it lets you customise the content of that notification before the user ever sees it

```
- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request
           withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler;

- (void)serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire;


class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {
var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

override func didReceive(
    _ request: UNNotificationRequest,
    withContentHandler contentHandler:
        @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)
{

    print (request.content.userInfo)
    self.bestAttemptContent = request.content
    //We can now change title 
    self.bestAttemptContent.title = "Welcome message"
    contentHandler (self.bestAttemptContent)
    return
}}
```

**NOTE :**
you need to have the key "mutable_content" and value 1 in your payload

```
"aps" : {
    "alert" : "Welcome Message"
    "badge" : 5
    "muatble_content" : 1
},
```

Comment: I think the title is not in the payload that I receive in my application. In the picture in my question it just shows alert = Hello; badge = 0. Why is there no "Title" in the payload? My cloud script is always sending push notifications with body and title, but in my iOS application the title is missing in the payload. Is it normal that there is no title in the iOS payloads or is it possible that there is a problem with my cloud script server code? In my Android application, I always receive the title in the payload.

Comment: @Hobbit7  
1. When there is no "Title" in the payload, OS will show the value of the key "alert" as notification Title.
2. Yes it is possible to have no "Title" key in the payload.
3. You can ask your backend team to update the payload format for IOS

Comment: Thanx. I will ask them because of the payload format for iOS. In the meanwhile, I use notification.AlertTitle = "New Notification!"; in my application code.